# Mobile web: from a user's profile page, how do I navigate between main and meta profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, mobile-web, per-site-meta

I was browsing a main site and saw a post from a particular user.  Hey, I wondered, whatever happened to that question this user asked on meta a few months ago?  On the desktop site that'd be no problem -- click the "meta profile" link and look around for the post.  With the mobile web site, though, that link doesn't exist.  (There's also no link to the network profile that I could see.)

I ended up going to the meta site, then going to the users list, then searching for that user, but that's not ideal -- especially when some user names start with those funky Unicode characters that I don't know how to type on my phone.

Is the link from main profile to meta profile (and vice-versa) there but I missed it?  If not, is there a better way to do what I was trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Being mobile view, some things are simply omitted on purpose, the link to meta is one of them.

The quickest way in my opinion is switching to the full site theme (there is "full site" link in the footer) then navigate to the meta profile from there. Once in Meta profile, you can tap "mobile" in the footer to get back the mobile theme.

Not ideal, but better and faster than searching by the user name on the meta site.

Comment: Ow, my poor eyes. :-)  Thanks for the suggestion; I think this somehow prompted me to think more broadly about the browser, which made me realize I could just edit the URL.  Also not ideal, but for me better than changing from mobile to desktop and back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I belatedly realized a faster way to do it, that is also easier for me than trying to navigate the full site on a phone: manually edit the URL to add (or remove) "meta.".

Sometimes bypassing the UI in favor of the direct URL is the way to go.

(This doesn't help with reaching the network profile, where URL-munging won't help.)